# Generate Oracle JSON from CLOB datatype column

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c, clob

Requirement is to generate JSON from clob data type column.
environment version Oracle 12.2

I have a table with fields id (number data type) and details (clob type) like below

```
ID   - details 

100  - 134332:10.0, 1481422:1.976, 1483734:1.688, 2835036:1.371

101  - 134331:0.742, 319892:0.734, 1558987:0.7, 2132090:0.697
```

eg output:

```
{
   "pId":100,
   "cid":[
      {
         "cId":134332,
         "wt":"10.0"
      },
      {
         "cId":1481422,
         "wt":"1.976"
      },
      {
         "cId":1483734,
         "wt":"1.688"
      },
      {
         "cId":2835036,
         "wt":"1.371"
      }
   ]
}
```

please help with oracle SQL query to generate output.

Comment: I don't understand. Where does pId 1788916 come from? Did you have that as Id originally (in the input table), then you changed that to 100 but forgot to change it in the desired output? Or what else?

Comment: Also: in your inputs, do the strings in the `details` column already include the double-quotes you show? Or is that just your way of indicating that they are strings? (I ask because in Oracle strings are enclosed in single-quotes, not in double-quotes.)

Comment: @mathguy yes my mistake, thats typo. pid is 100.
no double quotes on the details field (its clob though).

Comment: corrected my question ,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I set up a table with a few input rows for testing; then I show one way you can solve your problem, and the output from that query. I didn't try to write the most efficient (fastest) query; rather, I hope this will show you how this can be done. Then if speed is a problem you can work on that. (In that case, it would be best to reconsider the inputs first, which break First Normal Form.)

I added a couple of input rows for testing, to see how `null` is handled. You can decide if that is the desired handling. (It is possible that no `null` are possible in your data - in which case you should have said so when you asked the question.)

Setting up the test table:

```
create table input_tbl (id number primary key, details clob);
insert into input_tbl (id, details) values
  (100, to_clob('134332:10.0, 1481422:1.976, 1483734:1.688, 2835036:1.371'));
insert into input_tbl (id, details) values
  (101, '134331:0.742, 319892:0.734, 1558987:0.7, 2132090:0.697');
insert into input_tbl (id, details) values
  (102, null);
insert into input_tbl (id, details) values
  (103, '2332042:  ');
commit;
```

Query:

```
with
  tokenized (pid, ord, cid, wt) as (
    select i.id, q.ord, q.cid, q.wt
    from   input_tbl i cross apply
           (
             select level as ord, 
                    regexp_substr(details, '(, |^)([^:]+):', 1, level, null, 2) 
                      as cid,
                    regexp_substr(details, ':([^,]*)', 1, level, null, 1) as wt
             from   dual
             connect by level <= regexp_count(details, ':')
           ) q
  )
, arrayed (pid, json_arr) as (
    select pid, json_arrayagg(json_object(key 'cId' value to_number(trim(cid)),
                                          key 'wt'  value to_number(trim(wt)))
                             )
    from   tokenized
    group  by pid
  )
select pid, json_object(key 'pId' value pid, key 'cid' value json_arr) as json
from   arrayed
;
```

Output:

```
 PID JSON                                                                                                                         
---- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 100 {"pId":100,"cid":[{"cId":134332,"wt":10},{"cId":2835036,"wt":1.371},{"cId":1483734,"wt":1.688},{"cId":1481422,"wt":1.976}]}  
 101 {"pId":101,"cid":[{"cId":134331,"wt":0.742},{"cId":2132090,"wt":0.697},{"cId":1558987,"wt":0.7},{"cId":319892,"wt":0.734}]}  
 102 {"pId":102,"cid":[{"cId":null,"wt":null}]}                                                                                   
 103 {"pId":103,"cid":[{"cId":2332042,"wt":null}]}
```